# Capture a crew shot of Agilent 6000 (DSO6034A) , python , pyvisa

Tags: python, pyvisa

I would like to capture a screenshot of an Agilent scope using the code below but I get fault, and print was canceled can you please help me, (VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): Timeout expired before operation completed) , thanks

```
import pyvisa as visa
import sys
# Example VISA address for a USB         connection:
VISA_ADDRESS = 'USB0::0x2A8D::0x1797::CN57046145::0::INSTR'

rm = visa.ResourceManager(VISA_ADDRESS, read_termination = '\n', write_termination     = '\n' )
# Define VISA Resource Manager
scope = visa.ResourceManager('C:\\Windows\\System32\\visa32.dll')

#print (scope.query('*IDN?'))
scope.write(':HARDcopy: STARt')
raw_data = scope.read_raw ()
f= open ('Shot.png','wb')
f.write (raw_data)
f.close
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your ```f = open('Shot.png' 'wb')``` line is missing a ```,``` between the ```'Shot.png'``` and ```'wb'```  If it isn't that, please post the full traceback error.

Comment: it wasn't that, I get VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): Timeout expired before operation completed) , thanks

Comment: Please include that in your post.  Are you sure you have the right USB address?

Comment: yes, I can communicate and print out the ID with no problem

Comment: Not sure that `:HARDcopy: STARt` is the best command. On [this forum](https://community.keysight.com/s/global-search/dso6034a) they used `:DISPLAY:DATA? PNG, SCR, COL`. Further in [this example](https://siglentna.com/application-note/programming-example-sds-oscilloscope-save-a-copy-of-a-screen-image-via-python-pyvisa/) they used `f.flush()` just before `f.close()`.